# What will happen if i realloc something to nothing

Tags: c, string, null, malloc, realloc

Lets say i did somthing like this:

```
char* m = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
m = (char*)realloc(m, 0)
```

what will happen to m? and will the memory be released?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In this case the behavior is implementation defined.

From the C Standard (7.22.3 Memory management functions)

> 1. ... If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is
>    implementation-defined: either a null pointer is returned to indicate
>    an error, or the behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value,
>    except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an
>    object.

For example the system can free the allocated memory and return a non-null pointer.

Comment: I did read here  if size is equal to zero, and ptr is not NULL, then the call is equivalent to free(ptr) https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc

Comment: @Irelia It is in the case when a new extent of memory with the specified size was allocated successfully. Otherwise the old extent of memory is not freed.

Comment: Ah that makes sense.

Comment: @Irelia: That is Linux documentation saying what Linux does. It *extends* the standard C language by specifying behaviors that are more stringent than the C standard (the allowed Linux behaviors are a subset of the allowed C standard behaviors). The question is not tagged Linux and does not say Linux is being used, so it should be answered with the C standard behavior, which allows `realloc(something, 0)` to behave somewhat differently from `free`.

Comment: @Irelia That is all depends on the implementation of realloc on the given system. It is the reason that the behavior is described in the C Standard as implementation defined.

Comment: I realize that now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> what will happen to m? and will the memory be released?

C is evolving in this area.

C17 updated this spec.

> "If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is implementation-defined: either a null pointer is returned **to indicate an error**, or the behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value, except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object.".
> C17dr 7.22.3

And has

> Invoking `realloc` with a size argument equal to zero is an obsolescent feature.
> C17dr 7.31.12 2

Best to avoid `realloc(m, 0)` and call `free(m); m = NULL;` to free the allocation.

`m = (char*)realloc(m, 0)` may not completely free memory resources and return non-`NULL`.